# "Non-equal" or "greater than" is quicker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I wonder which of the following is done quicker for a tuple (also for a list or an int) :

```
a_tuple = ('a', 'b',)
```

1. `if (len(a_tuple) != 0): pass`
2. `if (len(a_tuple) > 0): pass`

I did some timeit experiment and the result is rather similar (vary each time I run timeit for 100000 iterations). I just wonder if there is a time benefit.

Comment: Micro-optimisations like this are rarely beneficial. If you need the speed, outsource this to C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `not a_tuple` (`True` if empty) or `tuple` (`True` if not empty) instead of testing for the length:

```
if a_tuple:
    pass
```

Or, as a demonstration speaks louder than words:

```
>>> if not ():
...     print('empty!')
...
empty!
>>> if (1, 0):
...     print('not empty!')
...
not empty!
```

Apart from the fact that this is a micro optimization, testing for the falsy-ness of the empty  tuple is faster too. When in doubt about speed, use the `timeit` module:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> a_tuple = (1,0)
>>> def ft_bool():
...     if a_tuple:
...         pass
... 
>>> def ft_len_gt():
...     if len(a_tuple) > 0:
...         pass
... 
>>> def ft_len_ne():
...     if len(a_tuple) != 0:
...         pass
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('ft()', 'from __main__ import ft_bool as ft')
0.17232918739318848
>>> timeit.timeit('ft()', 'from __main__ import ft_len_gt as ft')
0.2506139278411865
>>> timeit.timeit('ft()', 'from __main__ import ft_len_ne as ft')
0.23904109001159668
```

Comment: Besides, it's like twice faster.

Comment: Wait, if you have an instance of an empty tuple, how it could "if a_tuple" be false?

Comment: @Ivaylo: Because the empty tuple is 'falsy'. In a boolean context it tests as False, just like the empty string or 0 (any number type). See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: @Martijn: Thank you very much for your help. Indeed, I remembered something like that, but it is nice to read it again. That is considerable time-saver for me, because I have millions of comparisons like this.